# Makefile- not outputting the executable

Tags: c, macos, makefile

I'm new to makefile. I'm not sure why the executable 'main' does not appear after compilation. The code compiles fine, but compiler says:

```
-lm: linker input file unused because linking not done

-ltiff: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Below is the makefile code:

```
INCLUDES = -I. -I../include -I/opt/local/include
CC = gcc
OBJS = image_io.o textfile_io.o main.o
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) -c -g
DESTDIR = ../bin
LDFLAGS = -L. -L../lib -L/opt/local/lib -lm
DEPS = file_io.h corr.h nmsimplex.h matrix.h /opt/local/include/tiffio.h \
       /opt/local/include/tiff.h

image_io.o: image_io.c file_io.h /opt/local/include/tiffio.h \
               /opt/local/include/tiff.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) -ltiff

textfile_io.o: textfile_io.c file_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.c file_io.h nmsimplex.h corr.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -fopenmp $< $(LDFLAGS)

main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(DESTDIR)/$@ -fopenmp $^ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o *~
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you including the linker flags in when you are not linking, only compiling?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't.

Comment: you're right. I was a bit new to the terms. but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you get the two warnings:

```
main.o: main.c file_io.h nmsimplex.h corr.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -fopenmp $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

You are compiling not linking, not need to put `$(LDFLAGS)` which are linker flags. These flags are only relevant for the `main` target and not for the `main.o` target.

> Makefile- not outputting the executable

Add a target:

```
 all: main
```

right after `DEPS` definition. The `all` target will be executed first and will execute `main` target.

Comment: Actually there is more wrong here.  The recipe for the `main` target doesn't build `main`, it builds `$(DESTDIR)/main`.  That's a no-no; it means every time you run `make` it will relink the program even if nothing has changed.  This rule should be changed so the target is `$(DESTDIR)/main`, and the first target should be `all: $(DESTDIR)/main`.